# How to transfer calculated data(avarage per month) from a source workbook to my master workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a **master workbook** with a file browser user form and a chart in **tabel 1** and the data for the chart in **table 2**.

Now the idea is to search for a **source workbook** via the file browser in the master workbook and transfer the relevant data from the **source workbook** to the **table 2** of the **master workbook**.

The data I need is basically an avarage per month value. I'm not sure how to reference one workbook to another, so that the calculated data from the **source workbook** appears in **table 2** of my **master workbook**?

**Summarized**:

- Master Workbook(Workbook 1): Is displaying the Chart, which is based
  on the data from Workbook 2.
- Source Workbook(Workbook 2): Is providing the necessary Data.

I basically need the vba code for the "**transfer button**" seen below.

[image]

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

**Browse Button**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fNames As Variant
    With Me
        fNames = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel File(s) (*.xls*),*.xls*", , , , True)
        If IsArray(fNames) Then .ListBox1.List = fNames
    End With
End Sub
```

**Avarage per Month Calculation**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim K As Double, Kn As Integer

Dim L As Double, Ln As Integer

Dim G As Double, Gn As Integer

Dim i As Integer, lastRow As Integer



lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



For i = 1 To lastRow

Select Case Range("H" & i)

Case "01.February"

K = K + Range("A" & i)

Kn = Kn + 1

Case "01.March"

L = L + Range("A" & i)

Ln = Ln + 1

Case "01.April"

G = G + Range("A" & i)

Gn = Gn + 1

End Select

Next i



Range("K1").Value = "February 2019"

Range("K2").Value = K / Kn

Range("L1").Value = "March 2019"

Range("L2").Value = L / Ln


End Sub
```

Comment: Your screenshot shows the average for Feb in cell B4 but your code is writing to cell K2.Which is correct, the screen shot ?

Comment: sorry for this, B4 is correct. I forgot to update my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As you are only selecting one file change the listBox to a textBox

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' select file

    Dim fname As Variant
    With Me
        fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel File(s) (*.xls*),*.xls*", , "Select FIle", , False)
        If fname <> "False" Then .TextBox1.Text = fname
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages

    Const YEAR = 2019

    ' open source workbook
    Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

    If Len(fname) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table 2") '

    ' scan down source workbook calc average
    Dim iRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim sMth As String, iMth As Integer
    Dim count(12) As Integer, sum(12) As Integer

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow

        If IsDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) _
            And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 1)) Then

            iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))   ' col H
            sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 1) ' Col A
            count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1 '

        End If
    Next

    ' close source worbook no save
    wbSource.Close False

    ' update Table 2 with averages
    With ws.Range("A3")
    For iMth = 1 To 12
        .Offset(0, iMth - 1) = MonthName(iMth) & " " & YEAR
        If count(iMth) > 0 Then
            .Offset(1, iMth - 1) = sum(iMth) / count(iMth)
            .Offset(1, iMth - 1).NumberFormat = "0.0"
        End If
    Next
    End With

    Dim msg As String
    msg = iRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Table 2 updated"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! 
The code worked with my "simple" test source workbook. But as soon as I try it out with the real data sheet I get the error message "cant recognize date". 

The real data sheet is huge with over 10k rows - quite a mess to be honest.

So my question now is:
How can I make sure that the code recognizes every date format? (01.February, 01.Feb.,01.02.2019 etc.)
How can I make sure that the code only considers the relevant data types in the respective columns and ignores all other stuff? 

Column A = integers(decimal numbers)
Column K = date format.

Comment: @PlutoX If K is a 'true' date then you may be able to simply replace the case statements with iMth = month( wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8) ) but if some are text it gets more complicated

Comment: If by true date you mean - "01.02.2019" than yes, it is. What part of the code do I have to replace exactly? I'm not sure how to adjust the case statements according to your feedback.

Comment: Do you mean like this? Case "01.Jan": iMth = month( wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8) )

Comment: Thank you! The code seems to work with the date format. My only issue right now is that in case there are "other" values in Column K & A i get an error message. How can I make sure that other values are ignored by the code to make sure that I dont get the error messages?

Comment: To be more specific:  the A colum contains Text values and date values and the K column contains also text values. 

Column A :  ignore text values and date values
Column K: ignore text values.

 Another thing I'm wondering about: the calculated avarage values are missing a "." - meaning, that instead of 95.5, its shows the value 955. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: No errors anymore. The only issue that remains is the calculated avarage value. Now it is displayed like 955.0 instead of 95.5. The decimal point is at the wrong position.

Thanks again for your time and help!